# Calling print(ls.str()) in function affect behavior of rep

Tags: r, rep

Begin a new R session with an empty environment.  Write a series of functions with a parameter that is to be used as the value of the `times` parameter in a call to `rep()`.

```
f <- function(n) {
  rep("hello", times = n)
}
f(x)
```

One expect this to fail, and indeed one gets:

```
# Error in f(x) : object 'x' not found
```

Modify the function a bit:

```
f2 <- function(n) {
  ls.str()
  rep("hello", times = n)
}

f2(x)
```

As expected, it still fails:

```
# Error in f2(x) : object 'x' not found
```

Modify a bit more (to see the environment in the console):

```
f3 <- function(n) {
  print(ls.str())
  rep("hello", times = n)
}

f3(x)
```

I still expect failure, but instead get:

```
## n : <missing>
## [1] "hello"
```

It is as if the call to `print()` makes rep work as though `times` were set to 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I received earlier today a report that the bug has been fixed in R-devel and R-patched.

The issue was that the test for missingness in the R sources did not consider the case of an interrupted [promise evaluation](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Promise-objects). A fix [has been committed](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2017-September/074936.html) by Luke Tierney and can be seen [on GitHub](https://github.com/wch/r-source/commit/25f9a003d14080fd899c3dfa7d38d3ac2d8f37f2).

Comment: Duh!  Accepting now,  (Still relatively new to Stack Exchange provedure ...)

Comment: @BrodieG, no way was I gonna wade into the R-devel-list reporting a bug without confirming first with the Big Dogs.  Hence my post here.

Answer (score 6):

This is not an answer, but too long to post as a comment. A minimal reproducible example is:

```
f3 <- function(n) {
  try(get("n", environment(), inherits=FALSE))
  rep("hello", times = n)
}
f3(x)
## Error in get("n", environment(), inherits = FALSE) : object 'x' not found
## [1] "hello"
```

The following is speculative and based on loosely examining the source for `do_rep`.  `get` starts the promise evaluation, but upon not finding the "missing" symbol appears to leave the promise partially unevaluated.  `rep`, being a primitive, then attempts to operate on `n` without realizing that it is a partially evaluated promise and basically that leads implicitly to the assumption that 'n == 1'.

Also, this shows that the promise is in a weird state (have to use `browser`/`debug` to see it):

```
f3a <- function(n) {
  try(get("n", environment(), inherits=FALSE))
  browser()
  rep("hello", times = n)
}
f3a(x)
## Error in get("n", environment(), inherits = FALSE) : object 'x' not found
## Called from: f3a(x)
# Browse[1]> (n)
## Error: object 'x' not found
## In addition: Warning message:
## restarting interrupted promise evaluation 
## Browse[1]> c
## [1] "hello"
```

Comment: I can already reproduce the code with only the `rep` line, no need for `try(get(…))`. In fact, I think `do_rep` simply does its manual argument matching wrong, bails out on a non-existent promise and pretends that *no* argument except `x` is set. The thing about the “partially unevaluated” promise is a red herring.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I don't follow. `f3a <- function(n) rep("hello", times = n); f3a(x)` doesn't reproduce this.

Comment: @Roland Argh, indeed. But `f3a()` does.

Answer (score 2):

```
f4 <- function(n) {
  print('test')
  print(ls.str())
  print('end test')
  rep("hello", times = n)
}
f4(x)

## [1] "test"
## n : <missing>
## [1] "end test"
## [1] "hello"
```

There's something within `print.ls_str`, from Frank's test on chat the follwing code exhibit the same problem:

```
f6 <- function(n) {
  z = tryCatch(get("n", new.env(), mode = "any"), error = function(e) e)
  rep("A", n)
}
```

Digging a little inside R source I found the [following code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/7f0ae7735816eccba5e2e507543f0486c264bc28/src/main/envir.c#L2023-L2045)

```c
#     define GET_VALUE(rval)                      \
    /* We need to evaluate if it is a promise */  \ 
    if (TYPEOF(rval) == PROMSXP) {                \
        PROTECT(rval);                            \
        rval = eval(rval, genv);                  \
        UNPROTECT(1);                             \
    }                                             \
                                                  \
    if (!ISNULL(rval) && NAMED(rval) == 0)        \
        SET_NAMED(rval, 1)


    GET_VALUE(rval);
    break;


    case 2: // get0(.)
    if (rval == R_UnboundValue)
        return CAD4R(args);// i.e.  value_if_not_exists
    GET_VALUE(rval);
    break;
    }
    return rval;
}
#undef GET_VALUE
```

<strike>I'm quite surprised this compile properly, as far as I remember (my C is quite far behind) `#define` doesn't allow spaces between the `#` and define.</strike>

After digging for that, I'm wrong, from [gcc doc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/cpp_1.html#SEC3):

> Whitespace is also allowed before and after the `#'.

So there's probably something around this part of code, but that's above my head to pinpoint what exactly.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "empty" (`NULL`?), but I don't think it does anything like that.  The reason is that

    f4 <- function(n) {
      print(ls.str())
      substitute(n)
    }

works as expected.  For example `f4(x)` returns `x`.

Comment: I think your attempt at an explanation is too simple. If I use `f3 <- function(n) {
  print(ls.str());
  print(n);
  rep("hello", times = n)
}` I get the interesting warning: `In print(n) : restarting interrupted promise evaluation`. So, apparently `print.ls.str` does something strange with the promise.

Comment: @Roland indeed, digging a little more, as `f6 <- function(n) {  z = tryCatch(get("n", new.env(), mode = "any"), error = function(e) e);  rep("A", n) }` exhibit the same behavior (the tryCatch is coming from print.ls_str (thanks to Frank for the headup on this part)

Comment: In any case, it's a bug and should be reported (probably to the R-devel mailing list).

Comment: @Roland Did you do it?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I've never posted on any mailing list and I don't plan to start now. It's very unfortunate that access to the R issue tracker had to be restricted.

Comment: @Roland It seems that Homer White did: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2017-September/074930.html

Comment: Yes, the bug has been filed and fixed.

Comment: @Homer You could self-answer and maybe change the title after the fix is in a stable release (which is what I did in a similar case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30035939/why-is-the-diag-function-so-slow-in-r-3-2-0-or-earlier )

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Frank, I took you up on it.